# Explanation of specific partition in dual boot windows 10 and ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, gparted

I am (advanced) beginner in Linux.
My laptop comes with DOS, and I installed Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 as dual boot. Everything goes fine. Now I need to resize my Ubuntu partition. I read about it for a while, also on stack exchange, but I'm still not sure how to safely do that because I have a specific case. Please see picture attached.

Windows is on Partition 4, and "free space 10 GB" are unallocated partition which I get after shrinking Partition 4. Ubuntu is on Partition 7 and 6.

My question is what should be on partition 5, which prevents me to connect "free space 10GB" with Swap? I cannot see anything specific about that partition with few partition managers.

Details: I thought it is something connected with windows, so I first changed "free space 10GB" with Partition 5, with some third party windows app. But after that, when booting, I see Grub2, but click on Ubuntu fail to boot. I was scared that Partition 5 is something connected with ubuntu, so I installed Gparted on liveUSB and bring back order of "freespae10GB" and Partiotion5, but it didn't solve problem, ubuntu still were not boot. I tried advanced ubuntu option from Grub2, and recovery, than fsck and dpkg, but with now succes - says that disk is mounted and abort. Also I use grub option, which successfully ended, but with no boot again. Finally, tried root option, and use terminal commands to see if I could acces my data, and play around with basic commands (ls, nano..), everything seems ok, and after that, attempt to boot was successful (don't know why and how).

Now situation is as on picture.
I am afraid to change order of "freespace10GB" and Partition5 again.
Also, even if I safely do that, I am not sure if I could resize Partition 7 with freespace10GB on left, because there is warning about moving root partition (I suppose that moving swap on the end will be no problem).

Any help will be appreciated.

[image: Disk partitions]

Answer (score 0):

Boot into live USB, open gnome disks/gparted in live environment and move partition 5 to the left and resize swap.

Comment: Best to have good backups as any resize has risks. I might make swap 2 or 4GGB. And maybe even totally delete current 16GB swap & comment out swap entry in fstab. Then move p7 left only leaving 4GB on right for new swap at end of drive, so out of the way. But moving left has higher risk as any interruption or power failure corrupts data. And then update fstab mount of swap with new UUID of new swap.